# Implementing Content Provider for Search Widget Auto Suggestions

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am implementing android search widget with auto suggestions enabled. I am getting auto suggestions displayed but when a suggestion is clicked, app is getting crashed. I posted the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827979/android-stack-nullpointer-on-selecting-a-suggestion-in-search-widget/34828630?noredirect=1#comment57399876_34828630).

My Doubts are

```
1. Should we implement ContentProvider to make auto suggestions to work?
2. If yes, kindly suggests what should I have it in query().
```

Note: My Search is very simple and not using SQLLite database.

Comment: My very basic solution would be create a list in the activity and show when some search results are matched

Comment: You should either fully implement a SearchManager/ContentProvider-based SearchView API or adapter/listener-based SearchView API. Or both. Don't implement half of one and half of another and expect it to work. I would recommend to stick with adapter/listener-based option - the OS-global search have been removed from Android years ago, so nobody would ever use the created ContentProvider besides yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment user1643723. Can you help with some sample code?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have simple enough code to demonstrate the whole thing clearly. Just use Google's tutorials (ignore anything, related to Intents/ContentProviders) and study docs and source code of SearchView and you should be fine. Alternatively, consider some third-party libs (lately I often find myself replacing support SearchView with own rewritten version, because of how tedious it is to customize).